# PmWiki - How to fix "clicking SAVE removes your edits and saves nothing" issue

Tags: linux, installation, wiki

I have an issue with a fresh install of pmWiki (and I see the same Q on http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/Questions * but with no answer posted!) and I wonder if anybody knew anything about it or how to solve it.

I've been playing with pmWiki on my local and I LOVE it. I'm installing it now for one of my client's intranet, and ostensibly the install has gone swimmingly.

BUT, when I make an edit to a page and click "Save", the new text that I have added dissappears and no change is saved. The change is not even preserved in the textarea. Clicking "Save" seems to remove any text that I add to the page.

wiki.d folder is 777, and I've installed everything as per my successful install on my local.

Well, any (relevant) comments are welcome I guess ;-)

- [quote] (November, 2006) When i try and save a change to any page, the change disappears and reverts back to the previous format. There is no error message and I created the wiki.d directory with access 777. I have just installed PMWiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run chmod 777 on the wiki.d directory? Or did you do chmod -R 777 wiki.d directory? If you didn't do the -R the files under wiki.d aren't going to be set to those permissions-so if the web user tries to change them it will fail.

Comment: Just done - to no avail. I didn't need to do this on my local and it isn't in their manual either. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem and found the fix here:

http://www.mail-archive.com/pmwiki-users@pmichaud.com/msg22364.html

"Hello Steve,

Thursday, February 23, 2012, 4:52:47 PM, you wrote:

> How I got into the situation of having more than one Site.EditForm, I 
>   don't know

original with a virgin install you get Site.EditForm in the wikilib.d
folder. Once you edit the page, via your wiki edit, you get the
edited version in wiki.d folder, and the version in wikilib.d is
ignored. page files in wiki.d have priority over wikilib.d
That prevents updates from overwriting your edited pages.

Best regards,
 Hans
 www.softflow.co.uk
"

In my case, I'd edited Site.EditForm and somehow borked it. After that any and all my page edits were being ignored.

As per the above, I found that a copy of Site.EditForm had been created in /wiki.d. So, I deleted it from /wiki.d.

(Now, I recovered a copy from backup to move the original copy of Site.EditForm back into /wikilib.d, so I'm not sure if deleting my borked version in /wiki.d was enough. Probably.)

Anyway, after this fix I was able to edit (and keep) my edits in Pmwiki again.